# How can I send player score to local storage?

Tags: javascript, html, storage, local, ranking

I want to add the score the player gets when playing the game to html local storage? 
how would I go about doing this?
furthermore, if it wouldn't be too much trouble for anyone, how could I retrieve the score from locals storage and place it inside a rankings table?
most of the code is there, just a few things I cant see to understand

https://jsfiddle.net/gugui3z24/ab4gaf15/2/

```
    /* This function is called when a logged in user 
        plays the game and gets a score */
    function updateScore(newScore) {
        //Get the JavaScript object that holds the data for the logged in user
        var usrObj = JSON.parse(localStorage[localStorage.loggedInUser]);

        //Update the user object with the new top score
        /* NOTE YOU NEED TO CHANGE THIS CODE TO CHECK TO SEE IF THE NEW SCORE
            IS GREATER THAN THE OLD SCORE */
        usrObj.topscore = newScore;

        //Put the user data back into local storage.
        localStorage[localStorage.loggedInUser] = JSON.stringify(usrObj);
    }


    /* Loads the rankings table.
        This function should be called when the page containing the rankings table loads */
    function showRankingsTable() {
        //Get a reference to the div that will hold the rankings table.
        var rankingDiv = document.getElementById("RankingsTable");

        //Create a variable that will hold the HTML for the rankings table
        var htmlStr = "";

        //Add a heading 
        htmlStr += "<h1>Rankings Table</h1>";

        //Add the table tag
        htmlStr += "<table>";

        //Work through all of the keys in local storage
        for (var key in localStorage) {
            //All of the keys should point to user data except loggedInUser
            if (key !== "loggedInUser") {
                //Extract object containing user data

                //Extract user name and top score
                htmlStr += "David";
                //Add a table row to the HTML string.
            }
        }

        //Finish off the table
        htmlStr += "</table>";
```

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: how to send the score a user gets to localstorage, then retrieve the score from localstorage and input it into a rankings to where other users scores are also shown

Answer (score 0):

First, I got really impressed when I saw the game you wrote. It looks neat!

I would start with reading the [LocalStorage API docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to get a sense of how does the LocalStorage works. Then I would recommend checking out a library that can facilitate use of the LocalStorage API like [storage.js](https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js/).

With storage.js your code that would be responsible for retrieving user score would be (for an example):

```
// Set user score
storage.set('score', 52.0);
// Retrieve user score
var storoage.get('score');
```

Comment: can you add it to the fiddle please?

Comment: You need to understand basics of localStorage API. Working code is here https://jsfiddle.net/ab4gaf15/5/

Comment: @Sagar I tried the code but I cannot see the high score is local storage?